# How to get specific text from a website using python2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to create a simple program that collects simple text from a website for an example if a user wants lyrics of a song how do I make the program collect it
e.g.

> https://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/runthejewels/closeyoureyesandcounttofuck.html
>   how to collect just the lyrics part from this website?

Comment: check something like beautifulsoup, lxml, requests, or scrapy for examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `requests` to get get the HTML and then use [`BeautifulSoup`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) to parse it. The following looks for an HTML comment just before where the lyrics start in the HTML and then finds the parent `<div>` that contains it. From that the text can be extracted:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Comment

r = requests.get("https://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/runthejewels/closeyoureyesandcounttofuck.html", headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.75 Safari/537.36'})
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")

for comment in soup.find_all(string=lambda text:isinstance(text, Comment)):
    if "Usage of azlyrics.com content" in comment:
        print comment.parent.text
```

This would give you something starting:

```
[Zack De La Rocha:]
Run them jewels fast, run them, run them jewels fast
...
```

These libraries can be installed if needed as follows:

```
pip install beautifulsoup4
pip install requests
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.... :)